# Странности с Winsock и кодами ошибок

Tags: c++, winapi, сеть, tcp, winsock

Есть клиент-сервер, при тестировании локально клиент и сервер все делают корректно. Запустил клиент на другой компьютер с другим IP-адресом, то же самое сделал и с сервером. Открыл перенаправление портов на роутере, открыл все порты в брандмауэре с обеих сторон. В итоге имею: клиент висит в положении SYN_SENT, а коды ошибок меняются c 10060 (timeout) на 10061 (connection refused), причем по-разному: может быть 3 кода 10060, а потом код 10061 или, например, 6 кодов 10061, а потом 10060 - явного закона никакого нет. Клиент и сервер на C++, win sdk ver 10.0.18362.0.  Товарищи, есть мысли по этому поводу?

Comment: пингуется ли сервер с клиентской машины?

Comment: @goldstar_labs нет, не пингуется

Comment: стало быть, сеть сконфигурирована неверно, для начала настройте сеть, чтобы пошли пинги, потом проверьте доступность порта, потом уже ругайтесь на винсок)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Немного запоздал с ответом, но отвечу на свой же вопрос :D. Оказалось, что сервер был привязан только к ***localhost***. В структуре `sockaddr_in` есть структура `sin_addr`, где поле `s_addr` не было равно `INADDR_ANY`, что как раз и означает привязку ко **ВСЕМ** интерфейсам. Без данного значения до вашего сервера никто не достучится.